# Does Qubes OS support opengl on discrete graphics?

Tags: opengl, qubes

How can I configure Qubes OS that a VM supports opengl for my nvidia graphics on my laptop (optimus)?

The laptop has a integrated intel card and a quadro K2000M. At least the quadro 2000 seems to be supported by Xen passthrough: http://wiki.xen.org/wiki/XenVGAPassthroughTestedAdapters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Qubes OS does not support OpenGL or any accelerated graphics of any kind in a VM. The document located at https://www.qubes-os.org/doc/user-faq/ states:

> Can I run applications, like games, which require 3D support?
>
> Those won’t fly. We do not provide OpenGL virtualization for Qubes. This is mostly a security decision, as implementing such a feature would most likely introduce a great deal of complexity into the GUI virtualization infrastructure. However, Qubes does allow for the use of accelerated graphics (OpenGL) in Dom0’s Window Manager, so all the fancy desktop effects should still work.

Comment: Well, that's only partially true. `dom0` will not out of the box, that is technically true.  however, you can pass through the dGPU to another VM - like a Windows VM and play your games there.